# ディレクトリを作成しても,mkdir(): No such file or directoryになる！

Tags: php, debugging

フルパーミッション

```
drwxrwxrwx  3 ■■■■  staff      96  8 22 11:50 ★★★★(ディレクトリ)
```

css.php

```
private function getHistory()
    {
        $css_history = array();
        $dir = Config::get('■■■■') . Config::get('■■■■') . '/' . $this->data['■■■■']['■■■■'];

        if(!file_exists($dir)){
            //ディレクトリが無い場合は作成
            var_dump($dir);
            exit;
            //mkdir($dir);
        }
```

で、URLにアクセスすると

```
string(80) "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/■■■■/■■■■/css/★★★★"
```

と表示され、css/を確認すると★★★★のディレクトリがなかったので、★★★★ディレクトリを作成しました。

次に、`exit;`を削除して`//mkdir($dir);`を有効にし、再度URLにアクセスすると

```
Fuel\Core\PhpErrorException [ Warning ]:
mkdir(): No such file or directory

APPPATH/classes/controller/design/css.php @ line 70
　(line 70はmkdir($dir);の部分)
```

この場合、ディレクトリ(★★★★)を作成したのにmkdir(): No such file or directoryと表示されるのは何が原因なのでしょうか。

他に必要な情報があれば提示します。

宜しくお願いします。

```
環境
XAMPP
macOS
phpstorm
```

Comment: 書き込みを実行しようとしているディレクトリの権限情報を追記してください。

Comment: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/■■■■/■■■■/css/★★★★の、★★★★の共有とアクセス権ですが、自分:読み/書き、staff:読み/書き、everyone:読み/書きにして、アクセスしましたが同じエラーが出ますね。

Comment: 最初は、自分:読み/書き、staff:読み出しのみ、everyone:読み出しのみに設定してました

Comment: メッセージ `string(80) " /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/■■■■/■■■■/css/★★★★"` ですが、文字列の先頭(` /Applications/...`)がスペース文字になっているのが気になります。写し間違いでしょうか？

Comment: これは写し間違いです。実際は" /Applicationsにスペース文字はありません。修正しておきます。紛らわしくて申し訳ございません。

Comment: phpには[dirname](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.dirname.php)と呼ばれる関数があるので再帰的に親をさかのぼって全部のディレクトリがキチンとあるか調査することは可能ですか？

Comment: ■■■■:~ ■■■■$ dirname /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/■■■■/■■■■/css/★★★★をコマンドに入力すると、
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/■■■■/■■■■/cssが表示されましたので、全部のディレクトリありますよね？

Comment: dirname は実在チェックはしていないので前のコメントの通り再帰的にfile_exists等を利用して実在チェックを実行してください

Comment: 「exit;を削除して//mkdir($dir);を有効にし」としたとき、上の「var_dump($dir);」では何が出力されていますか？同じ「string(80) "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/■■■■/■■■■/css/★★★★"」ですか？

Comment: var_dump($dir);

Comment: mkdir($dir,0777,true);

Comment: 上記コードで、mkdir(): Permission deniedになります。

Comment: var_dump($dir);の結果は何も出力されていないということですか？

Comment: var_dump($dir);の結果はブラウザ上に表示されていません。

Comment: 再度、exit;を追記して、//mkdir($dir);にすると、string(80) "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/■■■■/■■■■/css/★★★★"がブラウザ上に表示されます。

Comment: 「mkdir($dir);」を「mkdir("/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/■■■■/■■■■/css/★★★★");」にするとどうなりますか？同じ結果になりますか？

Comment: ■■■■や★★★★に日本語などの二バイト文字は含まれていますか？

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82121/discussion-between-emus-and-blockchain2018)しましょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

たぶん★★★★ディレクトリを作成しようとしていると思うのですが、その親ディレクトリのcssが存在しないんじゃないでしょうか？

```
mkdir($dir);
```

を

```
mkdir($dir,0777,true);
```

に書き換えて試してみてください
第二引数、第三引数の詳細については、以下のPHPの公式を参照してください。
http://php.net/manual/ja/function.mkdir.php

Comment: 親ディレクトリのCSSは存在しています。mkdir($dir,0777,true);にすると、Fuel\Core\PhpErrorException [ Warning ]:mkdir(): Permission deniedになりました

Comment: css/★★★★の、★★★★の権限は自分:読み/書き、staff:読み/書き、everyone:読み/書きにしています。Permission denied(アクセス拒否)になるのは何が原因だと考えられますか？

Comment: ちなみに★★★★の親ディレクトリも親の親のディレクトリも権限を、自分:読み/書き、staff:読み/書き、everyone:読み/書きにしています。

Comment: 試しにコマンドライン上でmkdirコマンドによって/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/■■■■/■■■■/css/★★★★2ディレクトリは作成できますか？

Comment: ■■■■:~ ■■■■$ mkdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/■■■■/■■■■/css/★★★★2
で、■■■■:~ ■■■■$ ls /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/■■■■/■■■■/css→bootstrap-theme.css fonts.css  ★★★★2 で作成できてますよね。

Comment: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs` の `everyone` のからの権限を「読み/書き」にして user17014 さんの `mkdir($dir, 0777, true);` を試して見るとどうなりますか？

Comment: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocsのhtdocsだけではなく、この4つ全ての権限を読み/書きにして試せばいいですよね？